# WorkFront / AtTask API $$TODAYe+6m flaw?

Tags: c#, api, attask, workfront-api

**The workfront API isn't returning the same results as our web report:**

On our web front-end on workfront one of the reports has a date range from `$$TODAYbw` to `$$TODAYe+6m` and it returned about ~500 rows.

I tried the same query on the API like so (formatted for easier reading)

```
/v7.0/RSALLO/search
?fields=DE:project:Probability,allocationDate,scheduledHours,project:name,project:status,roleID,project:status,role:name
&allocationDate_Mod=between
&allocationDate=$$TODAYbw
&allocationDate_Range=$$TODAYe+6m
&AND:0:project:status_Mod=notin
&AND:0:project:status=CPL
&AND:0:project:status=DED
&AND:0:project:status=REJ
&AND:0:project:status=UZF
&AND:0:project:status=IDA
&AND:0:roleID_Mod=in
&AND:0:roleID=55cb58b8001cc9bc1bd9767e080f6c10
&AND:0:roleID=55cb58b8001cc9bd9fc0f8b03a581493
&AND:0:roleID=55cb58b8001cc9bfaa01243cd6024b6d
&AND:0:roleID=55cb58b8001cc9c0afa399dece405efd
&$$LIMIT=1000
```

which returned barely any results. Notice the `&allocationDate_Range=$$TODAYe+6m` line. If I change it to read `=$$TODAY+6m` without the *end of day* modifier the API returns ~500 rows.

I went through every filter criteria and it's only the allocationDate range that is going wrong. I found [this resource](https://github.com/Workfront/workfront-api-constants/blob/master/src/constants.ts) for the date modifiers and in it there is no `e+6m` example, yet it works on our web front-end report.

Is the API flawed or is the web report doing something extra in the background?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an exact solution for your problem, but I can confirm that the API does have some difficulty parsing wildcards like you're trying to use and they don't always come up the way we expect. Furthermore, the API doesn't parse things the same way as text mode reporting, so a query that looks great in the latter might return something different in the former.

If I may propose a different solution, since you're already coding this up outside of Workfront then I suggest you simply perform the date calculations on your own and pass explicit datetime objects to Workfront instead of allowing it to use its own logic. I know this doesn't answer the question of "what is a query that will return exactly what I want" but it should give you the correct end result.

For what it's worth, I spent about 15 minutes trying to get an example working on my end and I gave up after it kept returning values which should have been outside of my own date range.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. The work-around is as you suggested, having the application figure out the datetime and then pass it to the API, but it does make converting the web reports to the custom program more tedious.

Comment: It would also be useful if the API returned a list of the parameters that were parsed from the request. That way we could see which values it added correctly.

Comment: I agree with your 2nd comment. I was trying to look at some returned timestamps to parse out what it was doing but like I said I got annoyed with it quickly. Since you already have some queries built out you are in a more difficult position, but if datetime queries are the only tricky thing, transforming those few items into an in-code solution shouldn't be the worst thing in the world. Perhaps someone else will come along who has dealt with this frustration before and has more relevant advice. You could try the official Workfront forums as well.